# Cannot seem to use $_POST twice on the same page

Tags: php, html, xml

I am trying to access different elements in an XML so I can edit them or add new ones from within a web page. I'm using PHP to loop through the parent tags and display in a select list then have submit button to POST the element selected - no issue.

I then use PHP to find all the names of the selected elements children, and display those names in another select list form. This displays the children in the list correctly however when I hit submit  it displays correctly if I echo $_POST("Section") but clears the previous $_POST("Page").

I think this has something to do with using action="", but interestingly if I change one them to GET it works as intended. I actually want a 3rd step into lower children again, so cannot use that solution as a dodgy workaround.

I wont post XML as it has sensitive data in it and you can just trust I am stepping through that fine, it's the php clearing $_POST that is the big issue for me.

Please go easy - I literally learnt how to make a basic html webpage in april.

Tried a bunch of different form action including the .php it is on, and also

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
```

As stated before - using one as GET and one POST seems to solve the issue

```
<?php

//pages processing and put into an array

$pages_array = array();

$xml = simplexml_load_file('XML/links.xml') or die ("Failed to load");

        foreach($xml->page as $page){

            array_push($pages_array, $page->name);

        }

$pagecount = count($pages_array);



?>

<form name="page_select" method="POST" action="">  

<select name="Page">

<?php   

        for ($i = 0; $i < $pagecount; $i++){

      print '<option>'.$pages_array[$i].'</option><br>';

    }       
?>

</select>

<input type="Submit" name="edit_page" value="edit"/>  

</form> 

<br></br>

<?php

       // save page selected into $pg and display page being edited

       $pg = $_POST["Page"]; 

       echo 'YOU ARE EDITTING PAGE: '.$pg;
?>
```

****** THEN FURTHER DOWN THE PAGE *****

```
<?php

        // section processing

    $section_array = array();

    $xml = simplexml_load_file('XML/links.xml') or die ("Failed to load");

        foreach($xml->page as $page){

            if($page->name == $pg){

                     foreach($page->sections->section as $section){

                       array_push($section_array, $section->name);

                      }
            }
         }      

    $sectioncount = count($section_array);

?>

<form name="section_select" method="POST" action="">  

<select name="Section">

       <?php    

        for ($i = 0; $i < $sectioncount; $i++){

            print '<option>'.$section_array[$i].'</option><br>';

        }

    ?>


</select>

<input type="Submit" name="edit_section" value="edit"/>  

</form> 

<br></br>

    <?php

        $sct = $_POST["Section"]; 

        echo 'YOU ARE EDITTING SECTION: '.$sct;

    ?>
```

I want output to remember both arrays after the second form is submitted, however due to the first POST variable being wiped it means I also lose the second array since when it gets back to pushing to $section_array $page->name can never = $pg since $pg is now empty

Comment: What do you mean by "the first POST variable being wiped"? Where does this happen?

Comment: excuse my lack of terminology. I submit the first form, and then write it to a variable $pg = $_POST["Page"]. When I submit the second form, $_POST["Section"] works fine, but $_POST["Page"] is cleared. I am guessing this is something with the order I am doing it all in, or something to do with refreshing the page - but I can't work it out for the life of me

Comment: You can only submit one form at a time. The contents of `$_POST` will depend on which form the user submitted.

Comment: Each time you submit a form, `$_POST` only contains the fields from that form.

Comment: OK right that's kind of what i suspected so thanks for that confirmation . Is there any easy way you can think of that will allow me to save $pg without having it overwritten every time the 2nd form is submitted?

Comment: Add it as a GET method instead or use $_SESSION to hold the $pg var

Comment: same issue using multiple GETs....and as stated I cannot use 1 get and 1 post as I'm actually needing to do the same thing again - so will have to use 2 of one of em regardless.

Comment: I am not sure I follow what you are trying to do, but you can always add [hidden inputs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden) (or visible for that matter) to any of your forms, to keep track of state.  So if you know `$pg`, you can include it as a hidden input on another form, and when that form is POSTed, that value will be in your `$_POST` again.  If as suggested you want to use `GET`, you need to use the same approach - include the current value in your form action, like `action="foo.php?pg=<?php echo $_GET['pg']; ?>"`.

Comment: These also don't seem to work :(

Goal is to select a XML element in a list. Submit form1. Use submitted selection to find more xml elements and populate another drop down list. Select and submit form2. use submitted selection from both form 1 and 2 to find another bunch of xml elements and create drop down. Select last xml element which will be edited. 

I have a local website that has bookmarks/links. These are all stored in an XML structure and I have php that assigns these to links to A tag buttons.The forms in question then decide which part of the XML structure to add new links to

Comment: Maybe try to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - AFAICT the XML isn't actually relevant here, you're just having trouble with forms (I could be wrong), so skip that, just include a few hardcoded items in your lists.  Formatting your code neatly will also make it easier for ppl to read, understand, and help.

Comment: Thanks @AdamHull - $_SESSION was my solution and very easy to implement - appreciate the suggestions by all!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you submit a form, the page is reloaded and PHP will only have access to the POST variables from the form that triggered the page reload. This means that as your second form is submitted, $_POST['Page'] ceases to exist.

There are many ways around this problem, here is a fairly simple one. In your second form, create a hidden input that contains the value of the $_POST['Page'] variable. That way, when the second form is submitted, the Page value will be propagated to the next step of the process. Adding this code to your section_select form should suffice:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Page'])) {
    ?>
    Page: <?php echo $_POST['Page'] ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="Page" value="<?php $_POST['Page'] ?>" />
    <?php
}

?>
```